# Absolute url in ActionMailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, actionmailer

I have an asynchronous job that sends an email to the user when it completes. I'm testing the send email function with rspec.

In environments/test.rb I have this line

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

In the action mailer view I have this line,

```
= link_to(@submission.title, @submission, {:only_path => false})
```

This generates a relative url

```
<a href="/submissions/1" only_path="false">Test Submission 1</a>
```

What I need is

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/submissions/1">Test Submission 1</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the named route directly instead of allowing Rails to generate it for you. So turn your link into this:

```
= link_to(@submission.title, submission_url(@submission))
```